# jQuery - What am i doing wrong. if - else statements. wrap() if element is parent

Tags: jquery, if-statement

Basic idea of my if else statements is this:

- **If** `.wrap` is parent element: do something
- **Else:** do something else

This might not make much sense but if you look at the code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/C6NQM/ ..it might

```
if( $('.wrap:parent'); ) 
    { $('.wrap').children().wrap('<div class="new" />'); }
else { $('.wrap').wrap('<div class="new" />'); }
```

Things work separately if i remove if and else, so i came to the conclusion that there's something wrong with my if condition.

Any ideas about what's wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want:

```
$('.wrap').each(function() {
    if($(this).children().length > 0) {
        $(this).children().wrap('<div class="new" />'); 
    }
    else { 
        $(this).wrap('<div class="new" />'); 
    }
});
```

[**Updated fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/C6NQM/2)

**Comments on your code:**

`if( $('.wrap:parent'))` will **always** evaluate to `true`. A call to jQuery always returns a jQuery object. You could do  `if( $('.wrap:parent').length > 0)`, but even then you would select all elements in your example, as `:parent` selects also nodes that have text nodes as children.

But even with that, the whole statement will work as follows: If there are any `.wrap` elements that are parents, wrap their children in a new element. If not, wrap the elements themselves.
So it will not treat every `.wrap` element individually.

**Update:** To cover every case (children, text content, empty), you probably have to do:

```
$('.wrap').each(function() {
    if($(this).children().length > 0) {
        $(this).children().wrap('<div class="new" />'); 
    }
    else if($(this).text().length > 0) { 
        $(this).html('<div class="new">' + $(this).text() + '</div>'); 
    }
    else {
       $(this).wrap('<div class="new" />'); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not just `if($(this).children().length)`?

Comment: @Matt: More expressive and easier to understand for beginners.

Comment: Your code does work but it seems awfully complicated compared to what im going for here. And http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/

Comment: @Lollero: Well, it is not 100% clear what you want to do. If you want to treat every `.wrap` element differently depending on whether it has children or not, you have to use `each`.

Comment: @Lollero The `.each()` is needed, because you want to check for every single `.wrap` separately if they are a parent or not. The other downside with your code is that `:parent` will also select those elements that have only textnodes as children, so to make it correct, you need to check `.children().length`.

Comment: i dont quite follow what you mean. Cause i dont really want to "select" any elements.. Doesn't that just state "IF .wrap is parent do something" only thing that matters to me is that it is parent element..

Comment: @Lorello: What do you not understand? What is it that you want to do? The `if...else...` statement does not work like: *If the element is a parent, do this, else do that*. It works like *If there are any `.wrap` elements that are parents, do this, else do that*.

Comment: @Lorello: See also my comment above. Whenever you pass a selector, you select elements. I mean, you could also just use `if( $('.wrap:parent').length > 0)` but this will select also the second `.warp` element.

Comment: @Lollero: Read about the `:parent` selector. It also selects those elements that have only text nodes as children. So also the second one in your example. If this is what you want, then use it.

Comment: @FelixKling thats my point.. i dont care what .wrap is :parent to.. as long as it is :parent to elements. Cause in the Execution i define what to execute, which will be .wrap elements .children

Comment: @Lorello: But this will not wrap the text in the second `.wrap`, as `.children()` only selects element nodes, not text nodes. Next time I suggest you also include an example for the `else` branch...

Comment: @FelixKling i did include example for else too? "else { $('.wrap').wrap('<div class="new" />'); }" I really dont understand where you're going with this.. my else statement would be the one to take tare of those elements that dont have children at all.. I dont see whats the problem. edit: Actually.. so youre saying is that it sees my second .wrap so that it is also parent but cant wrap it cause it doesnt have children elements ( tags )

Comment: @Lollero: I mean you should have elements in your HTML code for which the `else` branch is executed, to see whether every case is covered and that it works. Please have a look at my update.

Comment: the second html .wrap was there.. i just didnt understand that  :parent did see it as parent element as well.. updated my comment above

Comment: @FelixKling just for the record. Your first code example was exactly what i want. I just didn't quite comprehend why :parent wasn't ok. I do now.. i believe. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and you code will work if you remove the ';' within the if condition.

Update:

PS: If you use jfiddle.net, general error in javascript will also be printed out in the error console of FireFox and Safari.